# @params comments defention in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, comments

i have a problem
my vs code do not know the type for my variables ( i need it for auto complitation)
i've tried to define them by this image
but as you see vs code has not suggest any completions

[image]

Comment: JSdoc isn't smart enough to know how to interpret that type, unless you are using their special import syntax. Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: no u am using javascriot